# compiling error for statistical modelling

Tags: model

While using [VECTRI model](https://gitlab.com/tompkins/vectri.git) and running this command:

```
(VECTRI/vectri/scripts/vectri_driver 5 highland_location_africa.txt 100 2100)
```

I am getting an error:

> +++ compiling the model +++ gfortran-mp-4.8 -I/opt/local/include  -c -O2 -Wall   mo_climate.f90 -o mo_climate.o -L/opt/local/lib -lnetcdff -lnetcdf make: gfortran-mp-4.8: No such file or directory make: *** [mo_climate.o] Error 1 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ERROR on compile

What is the solution for this error as I am getting stuck while on compiling?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the model you are using is for disease stats estimation. With the limited information you provided, most probably its a compilation error. Macports gfortran may not be activated on your system.
Try  to see what all are present in your gcc
$ port select --list gcc

If gfortran-mp-4.8 present,
set it by
$ sudo port select --set gcc gfortran-mp-4.8

Then $ hash -r

Then retry compilation. Hope this works.